# Microsoft Azure API Management - Cache policy doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, cache-control, policies, ibm-api-management

I have tried to set a caching policy in Azure API Management as follows:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" must-revalidate="true" downstream-caching-type="none" caching-type="internal">
            <vary-by-query-parameter>KontoNr</vary-by-query-parameter>
        </cache-lookup>
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="LogicApp_GeldEinzahlen_APIM_f597e3433e7847cb9d689c3f95bf1d6d" />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/1b7c4ba5-7701-49e7-94d8-5ddbc87f8b6e/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="aud">
                    <value>7068cdb6-0e5c-49c5-aaa8-ec8fc941de22</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
        <set-variable name="isKontoNr" value="@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["kontoNr"].ToString().Length != 10)" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("isKontoNr"))">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                    <set-header name="WWW-Request" exists-action="override">
                        <value>Generell error="kontoNr invalid"</value>
                    </set-header>
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <cache-store duration="1000" />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I have pricing tier "Developer" so the internal cache has to be available but if i make a request i always get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

cache-control: no-cache
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 15:54:26 GMT
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

cache-control is always 'no-cache' no matter what i send in the header.

How can i fix it ? Is some other configuration needed or have i enable something?

Comment: the no-cache pragma should not really be indicative whether the cache was being used. Go to the testing page in APIM, run a query and look a the traces. There you will see whether cache lookup was used

Comment: Hi Pascal, if the answer I provided below helps your question, could you please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) it as "accepted", thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As silent mentioned in comments, the message `cache-control: no-cache` should not really be indicative whether the cache was being used. The `<cache-lookup>` policy is correct in your APIM.

When you request the api(for test in APIM page) first time, click "**Trace**" --> "**Inbound**". You can find the message `Cache lookup resulted in a miss` because there is no cache when you request first time.
[image]

And then click "**Outbound**", you can find `Response will be buffered during streaming and stored in the cache after it is received in full`.
[image]

Then, since you specified the cache be stored for 1000 seconds, so if you request again in 1000 seconds, you can find the message `Cache lookup resulted in a hit!` under "**Inbound**".
[image]

Please test in your side, and if the result is same with what I mentioned above, the policy `<cache-lookup>` works fine in your APIM.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that caching isn't enabled by default for requests with the Authorization header. Allowing caching of private responses solved this issue.

Comment: Setting allow-private-response-caching="true" attribute on <cache-lookup> element of policy worked for me.